# Stored procedure logic based on table/column existence

Tags: sql-server, sp-executesql

I have a huge set of stored procedures that replicate an entity (that spans over 30 tables) from various environments we are working on: **Dev/Integration/PreProd/Prod**.

The idea is sometimes the DB structure changes from a platform to another. In general we're taking about small changes, like moving 1-2 columns to a new table or adding new table to the structure, etc.

Taking into account the complexity of this replication, I would like to have a single version of those procedures on all environments, no matter the difference related to DB structure, so that replication to be possible from any environment to another. For example, if the column exists in **src** and **dest** => do that logic, otherwise do other logic, etc.

**The idea is I cannot use an in-existent column in a stored procedure even the code checks column existence and that branch of code is never executed.**

The best found option was to write code with `sp_executesql`, but the code gets really complicated: it is just too much taking into account I'll have to throw away portions of the code once a structure change is aligned on all environments.

Comment: I think we're confusing the work 'migrate' here. To most people this means moving from one version of the schema to the next (adding/deleting columns and tables, updating stored procedures, etc). You seem to be using it to mean 'replicate': copy data from one server to another. Could you clarify?

Comment: @TimRogers: just changed the word to "replicate", hoping that will not interfere with SQL Server replication mechanism.

Comment: This would be easier for me to understand if you provided some reasonable example. Maybe an example change with a stripped down sproc  before and after. As is, it just isn't concrete enough.

Comment: @KarlKieninger: Let's suppose you have a "house plan" stored in about 30 tables in the database (a table for house structure, a table for palette of colors, etc). Once the DEV team finish it's job, the plan house is "promoted" on integration where also exists the good images/palettes developed by a designer. When everything is ok, then it goes to PRE-PROD where "the house plan" is shown to the client and some minor changes are made on different properties (for example change a color in a palette, etc). SPs are something like this: usp_CopyDataFromTableA, usp_CopyDataFromTableB, etc

Answer (score 2):

I would make sure all the tables you need and all future tables have an identifiable naming convention so you can query the tables/columns to be replicated using the sys.all_objects and sys.all_columns tables. In this example, you can pass the Source DB name to the Stored Procedure via the @SourceDB parameter and perform an insert where the Source/Destination table/column names intersect. The Destination DB isn't specified since it is presumed to be the Current DB:

```
-- get intersecting table/column names from @SourceDB
-- and Destination (Current) DB
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
set @sql = 'select o.name,c.name
    from ' + @SourceDB + '.sys.all_objects o
        inner join ' + @SourceDB + '.sys.all_columns c
            on c.object_id = o.object_id
    where o.type = ''U''
    and o.name like ''SomeStringToIdentifyYourTables%''
    intersect
    select o.name,c.name
    from sys.all_objects o
        inner join sys.all_columns c
            on c.object_id = o.object_id
    where o.type = ''U''
    and o.name like ''SomeStringToIdentifyYourTables%'''   
declare @TblColNames table(TblName nvarchar(200),ColName nvarchar(200))
insert into @TblColNames
exec(@sql)

-- insert data from Source DB to Destination (Current) DB
-- where Table/Column Names Intersect
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
set @sql = ''
select @sql = @sql + 'insert into ' +
    o.name + ' (' + replace((
                    select c.name +
                        case row_number() over(order by c.name desc)
                        when 1 then '' else '||' end
                    from @TblColNames c
                    where c.TblName = o.TblName
                    order by c.name asc
                    for xml path('')),'||',',') + ')
    select ' + replace((
                    select c.name +
                        case row_number() over(order by c.name desc)
                        when 1 then '' else '||' end
                    from @TblColNames c
                    where c.TblName = o.TblName
                    order by c.name asc
                    for xml path('')),'||',',') + '
    from ' + @SourceDB + '..' + o.name + '
'
from @TblColNames o
exec(@sql)
```

Comment: Nice idea, even it doesn't fit with the post.

Comment: How doesn't it fit with the post? Is there something you didn't mention that prevents this from solving your issue?